# How to minify js files with Grunt uglify and save path structure

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

Here's my question in topic.

I supposed, that i can write something like this:

```
uglify: {
  main_task: {
    files: [{
      //my working directory
      cwd: 'wd',

      // all my scripts and paths within directory
      src: 'src_path/**/*.js'

      // path to push all minified js-files with src_path directory structure
      dest: 'dest_path/'
  }
}
```

How can i tell Grunt, that i want to fold my minified files in dest path with inherit structure? Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure grunt-contrib-uglify to minify files while retaining directory structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18613164/how-to-configure-grunt-contrib-uglify-to-minify-files-while-retaining-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to set the `flatten` flag to false:

```
uglify: {
  main_task: {
    files: [{
      flatten: false,

      //my working directory
      cwd: 'wd',

      // all my scripts and paths within directory
      src: 'src_path/**/*.js'

      // path to push all minified js-files with src_path directory structure
      dest: 'dest_path/'
  }
}
```

Comment: That's great advice, but another problem is to tell Grunt to push all minified files and directories with them into new directory. How can I do that?

Comment: you could copy the unminified files to a new directory first and then minify them